# Behavior of solution to a ODE near a singular point

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, singularity

I want to see how the solution to the following ODE looks near `z=z0`.

```
 g[z_] := 1 + 3 (z/z0)^4 - 4 (z/z0)^3
 de = x''[z] + D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) x'[z] +  (w^2)/(g[z])^2 x[z] == 0;
```

If I expand the co-efficient of `x'[z]` and `x[z]` near `z=z0` :

```
D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) = 2/(z - z0) - 2/(3 z0) + (11 (z - z0))/(9z0^2) 

(w^2)/(g[z])^2 = (w^2 z0^4)/(36 (z - z0)^4) - (2 (w^2 z0^3))/(27 (z - z0)^3)
```

1. Now if I apply the "method of dominant balance" and keep only `x''[z]` and `(w^2 z0^4)/(36 (z - z0)^4) x'[z]` I get the following DE

   ```
    x''[z]+ (w^2 z0^4)/(36 (z- z0)^4) x[z] == 0
   ```

Solution  :   `E^(I (z0^2 w)/(6 (z0 - z))) (z0 - z)`

2. Whereas if I keep `2/(z - z0) x'[z]` term too I get the following DE

   `x''[z] + 2 / (z - z0) x'[z]+ (w^2 z0^4)/(36 (z - z0)^4) x[z] == 0`

   whose solution is :   `E^(I (z0^2 w)/(6 (z0 - z)))`

I find it a bit confusing. Actually I want to study the near `z=z0` behavior of the solution. I would expect the solution to be some power series with a singular part as a pre-factor :

```
x[z]=  E^(I (z0^2 w)/(6 (z0 - z)))( 1+ a (z-z0) + b(z-z0)^2)
```

Comment: What is your *Mathematica* question here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.